"gpg: decryption failed: No secret key" When secret key exists
Using gpg from the commandline I've created a public/private keypair.
I have then written a plaintext message and encrypted it with my public key.
When I attempt to decrypt the message, I get the response:
"gpg: decryption failed: No secret key"
So how do decrypt a message?

Can you share the commands for encrypt and decrypt you tryed?

Also please edit your question to show the command you used to create the public/secret key, and the command you use to verify (list) the key.
